Yii2 Авторизациа в тете и в api
у меня есть тест checkUserAuthorized в папке frontent/tests в котором юзер авторизован
 public function checkUserAuthorized(ApiTester $I)
    {
        $dummyLogin = DummyUser::findIdentity('dummyUser');
        Yii::$app->user->login($dummyLogin);

        $I->haveHttpHeader('accept', 'application/json');
        $I->haveHttpHeader('content-type', 'application/json');


        $I->sendPost('/frontend-api-url/user/check-user');

    }

и есть api endpoint в папке frontent/modules/frontend-api-url
public function actionCheckUser()
    {

        if (Yii::$app->user->isGuest) {
            return 'Пользователь не авторизован';
        }else{
            return 'Пользователь авторизован';
        }
    }

я хочу что бы dummyUser который авторизован в тесте checkUserAuthorized был и авторизован в endpoint-е actionCheckUser. то есть что бы actionCheckUser возврашал 'Пользователь авторизован'

Ну сделайте двух DummyUser'ов..... DummyUserGuest и DummyUserAuthorized, где один - гость, а другой - авторизованный. И сделайте два теста на два юзера...или один но с двумя этими самыми юзерами.
